# how to set div slide down and slide up with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

If `news_img` hover should be hide top to bottom else `news_img` show bottom to top. I tried with this. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harshana2007/qXwMD/2/)

Comment: So, what is the question? You think, that your code isn't good enough?

Comment: `#news_img` always show top to bottom. just i need how to show bottom to top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/). Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#news").hover(function(){
        $('#news_img').animate({
            height: 'toggle'
            }, 290, function() {
        });  
    });      
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qXwMD/7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can hide `#news_img` by default:

```
#news_img{ 
    display: none;
}
```

and use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#news").hover(function(){
        $("#news_img").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qXwMD/4/)**

Comment: sir. It's ok but `#news_img` always show top to bottom. just i need how to show bottom to top ?

Comment: I don't get what you means. What you've describe is exactly the same as your fiddle in the question, isn't it?

Comment: no sir. See hover on the `#news_img` then it's hiding to upside. i need to hide that downside